# SQL Statement If statement inside a SELECT statement

Tags: postgresql, select, if-statement, jasper-reports, ireport

Is there a way that I can use if statement in a select statement?

I cannot use Case statement in this one. Actually I am using *iReport* and I have a parameter. What I want to do is if a user does not enter a certain parameter it will select all the instances.

For example a table of person referencing to gender table, a with a parameter on where clause, query would go like:

```
SELECT * FROM persontable WHERE gender_id = $P{genderName}:numeric
```

If the parameter **$P{genderName}** is null or blank then it will select all. I tried this query:

```
SELECT * FROM persontable WHERE gender_id IN (SELECT CASE WHEN $P{genderName} 
 IS NULL THEB (SELECT id from genderTable 
 WHERE id = $P{genderName}:numeric) ELSE $P{genderName}::numeric END)
```

But it will return an error "More that one row is returned....." I think it is because of the CASE statement. How do I this?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM persontable 
WHERE gender_id = $P{genderName} OR $P{genderName} IS NULL
```

Comment: Might have to tweak it for iReport, I don't know anything about that.

Comment: Let me try that. I dont understand that but let me try that.

Comment: If the gender_id matches what you specified in the parameter then the record will be returned, if there was no parameter then the other side will always be true so every record will be returned.

Comment: If it worked can you let us know and mark as answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily achieved using an ***Auxiliary Parameter***.

Define a new parameter in your report, call it, `aux_gendername`.

While defining the parameter, tweak its *Default Value Expression*.

```
($P{gendername}.equals("") || $P{gendername}==NULL? " " : " and gender_id = '"+$P{gendername}+"'")
```

Then in your main query, instead of the actual parameter ($P{gendername}) use the auxiliary parameter.

```
SELECT * FROM persontable WHERE 1=1 $P!{aux_gendername}
```

If the $P{gendername} contains any value *and* condition will dynamically be appended to the  query else the entire resultset would be displayed in the report without any filtering.

***Note***: Using a *!* in the auxiliary parameter is mandatory.